# Verify a method is called or not in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq

I have a unit test I am checking whether a method is called once or not so I attempted this way:-

This is my Mock of `ILicenseManagerService` and I am passing its object through constructor.

```
    public Mock<ILicenseManagerService> LicenseManagerService { get { return SetLicenseManagerServiceMock(); } }

        private Mock<ILicenseManagerService> SetLicenseManagerServiceMock()
        {
            var licencemangerservicemock = new Mock<ILicenseManagerService>();
            licencemangerservicemock.Setup(m => m.LoadProductLicenses()).Returns(ListOfProductLicense).Verifiable();

            return licencemangerservicemock;
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<IProductLicense>> ListOfProductLicense()
        {
            var datetimeoffset = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);

            var lst = new List<IProductLicense>
            {
                GetProductLicense(true, datetimeoffset, false, "1"),
                GetProductLicense(true, datetimeoffset, false, "2"),
                GetProductLicense(true, datetimeoffset, true, "3")
            };

            return lst;
        }
```

I am using this mock object to set `_licenseManagerService` and calling the `LoadProductLicenses()` in method under test. like this. **licences are coming fine.**

```
    var licenses = (await _licenseManagerService.LoadProductLicenses()).ToList();
```

My attempt for verify the call to this method -

```
     LicenseManagerService.Verify(m => m.LoadProductLicenses(),Times.Once);
```

But when I run my unit test, an exception coming that say method is not invoked at all.
Where I am doing wrong ?

**EDIT** @dacastro I am invoking the same mock here is my unit test.

```
    [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("InApp-InAppStore")]
        public async Task return_products_from_web_when_cache_is_empty()
        {
            // this class basically for setting up external dependencies
            // Like - LicenceManagerService in context, i am using this mock only no new mock.
            var inAppMock = new InAppMock ();                  


            // object of Class under test- I used static method for passing external         
            //services for easy to change 
            var inAppStore = StaticMethods.GetInAppStore(inAppMock);

            // method is called in this method
            var result = await inAppStore.LoadProductsFromCacheOrWeb();

            // like you can see using the same inAppMock object and same LicenseManagerService
            inAppMock.LicenseManagerService.Verify(m => m.LoadProductLicenses(),Times.Once);
                      

        }
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
LicenseManagerService.Verify(m => m.LoadProductLicenses(),Times.Once);
```

By calling the `LicenseManagerService` property, you're creating a *new* mock object. Naturally, no invocations have ever been performed on this instance.

You should change this property's implementation to return the same instance every time it is called.

Comment: i am sure that i am using the same mock object. can you see the edit.

Comment: @loop can you post the definition for `InAppMock.LicenseManagerService`?

Comment: It is at the top most. actually LiceneseManagerService is one of the property of InAppMock Class.Basically InAppMock class provide Mock of external dependencies. I have done to use it in multiple test cases.

Comment: Then that's your problem. `inAppMock.LicenseManagerService.Verify` creates a new mock instance every time it is called. You should change the property's implementation to return the same instance every time.

Comment: Got it dcastro. Thanks it is the problem :). can you update your ans a litle bit. so that I can mark it right.